# How to set external ID in UniqueIdentifier class

Tags: kotlin, corda, uniqueidentifier

Can somebody tell me how to best set the `externalID` when creating a new `UniqueIdentifier`? The below does not work.

```
UniqueIdentifier linearid = new UniqueIdentifier(stringVar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the constructor a UUID also:

```
UniqueIdentifier linearid = new UniqueIdentifier(java.lang.String stringVar, java.util.UUID id);
```

And then to retrieve and use your id, you will call the getExternalId() method:

```
String myExternalId = linearid.getExternalId();
```

https://docs.corda.net/api/javadoc/net/corda/core/contracts/UniqueIdentifier.html

Comment: Thanks but I checked that link before and it states "id - Should never be set by user code and left as default initialised. So that the first time a state is issued this should be given a new UUID. ....". So if i'm not allowed to set the UUID then how to instantiate the UniqueIdentifier class whereby I pass the external ID (e.g. purchase order number)?

Comment: Did the following and it works fine `this.linearid = new UniqueIdentifier(externalreference, UUID.randomUUID());` just surprised I have to provide the UUID.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in my Kotlin code:

```
val linearId = UniqueIdentifier("externalIdHere")
```

Looking at the function the UUID.randomUUID() should act as the default parameter for the id: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/contracts/UniqueIdentifier.kt#L23